# Multiple version of Angularjs with JSONP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I developed an application using angularjs, ui-bootstrap and JSONP (so that people can use my app on their website on cross domain). The problem is that there can be a conflict btw my version of angular with the one on the website. I can't use or overwrite the version on the website (I already had some problems migrating from version 1.1.5 to 1.2.1). And I can't tell them to upgrade or downgrade...I want it to be a flexible app.
Is there a way to have multiple versions of Angular like the noconflict of jquery? Of course I want to avoid the one using my app to handle that conflict.
Thank you in advance for your solutions.